# Firefox Can't Bookmark

Tags: windows-10, firefox, bookmarks

Can I know the reason why Firefox can't bookmark any page? The button isn't working at all.

[image]

I had just downloaded and installed it.  Bookmark fails to work that since I launch it. I'm using Windows 10 64bit.

Comment: Does it work when you press CTRL+D?

Answer (score 0):

This occurs if you failed to install it on default dir.
You can try a shortcut Ctrl+D for current bookmark or add shift for all bookmarks. 
I think latest update have some patch issues. 
Also read the blog they wrote for [shortcuts](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly).